# ruby on apache not keeping connection alive

Tags: ruby, apache, keep-alive

I have a ruby on rails app serving an API. It's legacy and we've already built a replacement on a more suitable stack, so no such suggestions in that direction needed :)

But we need to improve the performance on it regarding latency of response. I noticed keepalive was off. So I enabled it in apache. Now the static files from that server are responding with connection: keep-alive in the response headers. But the api (dynamic, rudy generated xml) still responds with connection: close. Sure enough it appears to be closing the connection on the client. Passenger is the Apache module used.

How can I make it use keepalive for the ruby generated responses?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce this. I just tried, with Apache 2.2.3, passenger 3.0.12

The responses from my rails app do not have connection:close, they are kept alive. (They in fact have a `Connection: Keep-Alive` too, although I don't think HTTP 1.1 requires that.

So long as my apache has `KeepAlive On`.